# Why is Chart.js canvas not responding to container width change caused by a margin-left change?

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, chart.js

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hkqh6gv/).
I use a toggle button to change container margin-left, which then changes chart canvas container width. But the chart doesn't seem to respond to the width change.

1. Html:

   ```
   <div id="app">
       <div id="sidebar">
           <button id="toggle">≡</button>
       </div>
       <div id="main">
           <div>
               <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
           </div>   
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. JS:

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {        
       $("#toggle").click(function () {
           var app = $("#app");
           app.toggleClass("side-open");
       });

       var data = {
           labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"],
           datasets: [
               {
                   label: "My First dataset",
                   fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                   strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                   pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                   pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                   pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                   pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                   data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
               }
           ]
       };
       options = {responsive: true};
       var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
       var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
   });
   ```
3. CSS:

   ```
   html, body{
       margin: 0;
   }

   #app{
       position: absolute;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
   }

   #toggle{
       width: 40px;
       margin: 5px;
       padding: 5px;
   }

   #sidebar{
       position: absolute;
       height: 100%;
       width: 50px;
       background: #ccc;
   }

   #main{
       padding: 5px;
       margin-left: 50px;
       position: relative;
       height: 100%;
   }

   .side-open #sidebar{
       width: 100px;
   }

   .side-open #main{
       margin-left: 100px;
   }
   ```

Comment: it seems your canvas not responsive but if you add `#myChart[style] { width: 100% !important; }` to your **CSS** you can achieve this. And dont worry about `!important` as it will only work when your `canvas` has inline **CSS**.

Comment: Nope, which is logical! When you load the page the graph is initialized and the width of the chart is set! After you click the toggle button you shift the whole section 100px to the right! You do not define that if you click the toggle button the chart should also adjust the size! setting the options: responsive will not do the trick for you!

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay your solution worked. :-).

Comment: @Rotan075 but im sure you're aware that adding a 100px margin to main will shrink its content width by 100px. The chart needed to automatically respond to a change in its container width.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay your solution somehow works, but it seems chart.js doesn't re-draw the chart. The canvas is simply just stretched or shrank to fill width. This distorts rendered text. Do I have to do update canvas manually?

Comment: @RealCaz What I would recommend is use width percentages and float the two div panels next to eachother and remove the `margin-left` part. Then if you click on the toggle button just shrink the width of the graph. See [JSFFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3vjm30sy/1/)